# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a problem whit my game. i want add a  Distance Highscore system but it does not work i look a lot of Tutorials but nothing works pls help.

```cs
{
    public Transform MainCamera;
    public Text ScoreText;
    public Text HighScoreText;
    public int score;
    
    
    void Start()
    {
    
        HighScoreText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore", 0).ToString();
    }
    
    
    void Update()
    {
        //MainCamera is follow the Player 
        score = MainCamera.position.x.ToString("0"); //here is the error 
        ScoreText.text = score.ToString();
        
    
    
        if ( score > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore", 0))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", score);
            HighScoreText.text = score.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```

i tried a lot of things but nothing does work.

Comment: score is an int, you are trying to put a string in it, what do you expect

Comment: Why do you have `.ToString("0")`? What are you trying to accomplish with that?

Comment: I really don't understand anything, I've watched a lot of videos and I now have this I want there to be a distance HighScore and the MainCamera thing is to count the distance.

Comment: @gunr2171 what should i put there?

Comment: What's the datatype of `x`? If it's an `int`, you don't need `.ToString()`.

Comment: Watching videos is not a good way to learn. Buy a proper book and start at the beginning, you can't skimp learning to program.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self-explanatory:

- `score` is of type `int`
- `MainCamera.position.x.ToString("0")` returns a `string`
- => you can't store a `string` in an `int`

`x` will be a `float` (see [`Transform.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html) and [`Vector3.x`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-x.html)) so you probably want

```
score = Mathf.FloorToInt(MainCamera.position.x);
```

see [`Mathf.FloorToInt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.FloorToInt.html) => always rounds down to the lower `int` value

or simply use

```
score = (int)MainCamera.position.x;
```

which for positive values basically does the same (and more efficient) and throws away any decimals